# pip is not recoginzed as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pip

I have tried setting my System variable Path=C:\Python27\Scripts\

I also have set User Variable Path=C:\Python27\

I can see it return correctly when I echo %PATH%

What else is needed for pip to work correctly?

Comment: did you install pip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my issue. Was running cmd prompt from P4 directly which was my issue. When running cmd prompt outside of P4 I was able to run pip with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pip too.

For convinience you can use some package manager to get started and going. Google for python package managers (anacond etc)

Comment: So I installed Python2.7.11 and pip gets installed with it.